# Is taraaweeh prayer obligatory for women?

Tags: taraweeh

Is taraaweeh prayer required for women?

Which is better for women, to perform Taraaweeh at home or in a mosque?

Comment: Taraweeh isn't even obligatory for men so why should it be the case for women?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assalamu'alaikum,

The ulema have some differences on taraweeh being sunnah mua'kkadah (emphasised sunnah) or simply nafl. This applies equally to men and women.

Nafl because the Prophet (s.a.w) stopped praying it in congregation after the third day whereas he was not known to have stopped the other sunnah mua'kkadah prayers except usually only for travel. Wallahu alim.

And sunnah mua'kkadah because the night prayer in the nights of Ramadan of which Taraweeh is one of - was greatly emphasised by the prophet sallallahu alaihi wa salam to pray it.

Regarding women praying taraweeh at home or in the mosque; the classical opinion of our ulema has always been that home is better than mosque for all prayers for women. However homes are sometimes very distracting places for women and many women are not able to reach much spiritual tranquility given the distractions of looking after family and household duties. In such situations, it may be advisable for women to make time and make provision to attend the Taraweeh prayers at the mosque.

Wallahu alim.

Comment: Welcome to islam.se, hope for more to come. inshallah. It would help to add some sources such as a fatwa, ayah in quran or specific hadiths.